# NHibernate BuildSessionFactory() ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am building a ASP.NET MVC project and am using NHibernate instead of Entity Framework.

The problem that am experiencing is that I get an ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog' when calling the BuildSessionFactory() method in the Configuration object.

```
config = new Configuration();
config.Configure();
sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

IList<Catalogue> catalogues = (from c in session.Query<Catalogue>()
                               select c).ToList();

return this.Json(catalogues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

My Connection String is

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Passion4Performance;Integrated Security=True</property>
```

I have tried many solution but nothing seems to fix this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file should look something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NameOfConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Passion4Performance;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">NameOfConnectionString</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```